# What causes a div to become focusable?

Tags: html, focus

If you navigate to https://basis.now.sh and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> 3 times, you'll notice that the div that contains the sidebar navigation becomes focused (or the `document.activeElement`).

[image]

Looking at the HTML, there is no special attributes like `tabindex` on the `div`.

[image]

What causes this `div` to become focusable, and how would you make it non-focusable?

Tested on:

- Chrome Version 83.0.4103.106
- macOS 10.15.4

Comment: Hm, for me, using chrome 83.0.4103.106, macOS 10.15.2 the playground link is focused and not the entire div

Comment: maybe it's a chrome extension causing this to happen (for some reason). Do you get the same behaviour in incognito mode (with no extensions enabled?)

Comment: Just tried in Incognito and also disabled all the extensions, and still I have to Tab 4 times to focus on Playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the offender in `chrome://flags`. I had this enabled:

[image]

After disabling it, the `div` isn't get focused anymore.